# how to grep only one numeric charcter

Tags: bash

I have a file as show below and I want to grep only numeric "1" but when I will give command grep and it grep every character which is have "1"

```
 0 turks-g         DD-Production-Server Incremental-Bac pls-i085-g      10/23/2013 18:04:53
 1 pls-w099-g      Production-PCI-Serve Incremental-Bac pls-i097-g      10/23/2013 18:05:36
 0 longjawed-g     DD-Production-Server Incremental-Bac pls-i086-g      10/23/2013 18:09:09
 1 pls-i085-g      NetBackup-Servers    Incremental-Bac pls-i085-g      10/23/2013 18:09:28
```

orion # cat tts |grep "1"

0 turks-g         DD-Production-Server Incremental-Bac pls-i085-g      10/23/2013 18:04:53
 1 pls-w099-g      Production-PCI-Serve Incremental-Bac pls-i097-g      10/23/2013 18:05:36
 0 longjawed-g     DD-Production-Server Incremental-Bac pls-i086-g      10/23/2013 18:09:09
 1 pls-i085-g      NetBackup-Servers    Incremental-Bac pls-i085-g      10/23/2013 18:09:28

orion # cat tts |grep '1'

0 turks-g         DD-Production-Server Incremental-Bac pls-i085-g      10/23/2013 18:04:53
 1 pls-w099-g      Production-PCI-Serve Incremental-Bac pls-i097-g      10/23/2013 18:05:36
 0 longjawed-g     DD-Production-Server Incremental-Bac pls-i086-g      10/23/2013 18:09:09
 1 pls-i085-g      NetBackup-Servers    Incremental-Bac pls-i085-g      10/23/2013 18:09:28

Please suggest me how can I grep only "1"

Thanks

sa

Answer (score 2):

Search with word boundaries:

```
grep "\<1\>" file
```

OR else use `grep -w`:

```
grep -w "1" file
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: thanks for you help and grep -w "1" file works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the patterns around the text of interest, i.e. beginning of the line and empty space.

```
cat tts | grep "^ 1 "
```

Comment: That is the original command found in the question, but with the suggested pattern.